# Can I stop ExcelDNA handled exceptions from occuring?

Tags: c#, error-handling, excel-dna

When building my application, I frequently like to have the "Pause on handled exceptions" option in SharpDevelop set to true (I understand than visual studio has a similar flag).

However it seems ExcelDNA throws a lot of exceptions when Excel is started (which are caught, so there is no problem in production).

This means that every time I want to debug my program effectively, I need to turn off this flag initially, and then turn it on again once excel has finished starting up.

Is there any way around this?

for example, the 1st exception is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ExcelDna.Loader' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at static RuntimeAssembly System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName fileName, System.String codeBase, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly locationHint, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, System.Boolean forIntrospection, System.Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at static RuntimeAssembly System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.Boolean forIntrospection, System.Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at static RuntimeAssembly System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at Assembly System.AppDomain.Load(System.String assemblyString)

Comment: Can you add a stack trace or two to show where these exceptions occur? I think you are seeing exceptions in Excel.exe itself, which we have no control over.

Comment: Ah, thanks. No - very hard to get around those exceptions, as they occur in the .NET runtime when an assembly load fails. It would be very hard to reimplement the assembly probing to test whether a load would succeed before trying it. Getting Excel-DNA bootstrapped from a single file in the somewhat hostile Excel process is a bit messy, unfortunately.